# Unavailable option on Apple clang only; version mismatch?

Tags: xcode, development

I want to use `clang`'s option `-ffile-prefix-map`. This option is normally available [since Clang 10](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38135).

Indeed, if I get a Docker image with clang (e.g. `docker pull silkeh/clang:10`), I can run it without any problems:

```
clang -ffile-prefix-map=a=b
```

However, the same command in my macOS 10.15.7 results in `error: unknown argument: '-ffile-prefix-map=a=b'`. If I run `clang --version`, I get:

```
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

This seems to suggest I have Clang 11, which *should* have the option.

Is this a quirk in Apple's Clang, or am I misreading its version? Is there some table showing matching versions between both Clangs, which would explain the error?

Comment: Unfortunately not easy, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36000632/151019 and https://gist.github.com/yamaya/2924292

Comment: clang --help does give a list of the command line options and (clang-1205.0.22.11) does have that option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a difference between LLVM clang  https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project and Apple Clang https://github.com/apple/llvm-project/ .

Apple Clang 12+ supports this flag IIRC.

To check if a flag is supported, you can write a C file with an empty main function and compile it with the flag of interest, and `-Wno-error`. If it exits with non zero status, the flag is not supported.